# 'Prefix not set' error showing, when trying to install 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

When I tried to install and reboot to Ubuntu 12.04,  I  got an error as 'prefix not set' and if I choose the option normal mode it is showing me another error.

Please help me with this. I have tried to install both 32-bit and 64-bit also, but the result is same.

Comment: How you installing Ubuntu?

Comment: And what is the error message? Post the complete message.

Comment: flagged as a possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/140991

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have downloaded the correct ISO CD by using their MD5/SHA1 checksums. I know this is quite obvious, but is the source of trouble in most cases.